# Find all the complex numbers $z$ satisfying the following conditions

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all the complex numbers $z$ satisfying the following conditions:

$$\bar{z} = z^{n-1} \text{ where } n>2 \text{ and $n$ whole.}$$

I'm not sure if I'm correct but:

$$|z|^2 = z^n$$

$$|z|^{2-n} = \cos(\theta n)+i\sin(\theta n)$$

$$|z|^{2-n} = e^{\theta ni}$$

$$\ln Z - \theta i = \frac{\theta ni}{2-n}  $$

since $n>2$ then it doesn´t hold for any number.

Comment: I edited your question to get it to render properly in mathjax; hope I got the math all right.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from

$\bar z = z^{n - 1}, \tag{1}$

we see that $z = 0$ is a solution.  If we assume $z \ne 0$, then we may take absolute values and obtain

$ \vert\bar z \vert = \vert z^{n - 1} \vert = \vert z \vert^{n - 1}; \tag{2}$

since $0 \ne \vert \bar z \vert = \vert z \vert$, this leads us to

$\vert z\vert^{n - 2} = 1, \tag{3}$

and since $n > 2$ we conclude that $\vert z \vert = 1$.  Thus we may write

$z = e^{i \theta}, \tag{4}$

whence

$z^{n - 1} = e^{i(n - 1)\theta} \tag{5}$

and

$\bar z = e^{-i\theta}. \tag{6}$

Equating (5) and (6) according to (1) we have

$e^{-i\theta} = e^{i(n - 1)\theta} \tag{7}$

or

$e^{i n \theta} = 1. \tag{8}$

(8) implies

$n \theta = 2m \pi, \tag{9}$

for some $m \in \Bbb Z$.  Thus

$\theta = \dfrac{2 \pi m}{n}. \tag{10}$

We note that only the $m$ such that $0 \le m \le n - 1$ are necessary to yield all the distinct nonzero values of $z = e^{i \theta}$, since the sequence $e^{2\pi m i/n}$ repeats itself every time $m$ passes through a multiple of $n$; there are thus $n$ non-vanishing solutions $z = e^{2\pi m i/n}$, $0 \le m \le n - 1$.

We check:  with $z \ne 0$ as above, we have

$z^{n - 1} = e^{2\pi m(n - 1) i/n} = e^{2 \pi mn i /n} e^{-2 \pi mi/n} = \overline{e^{2 \pi im/n}} \tag{11}$

since $e^{2 \pi mni /n} = e^{2 \pi mi} = 1$.  This shows that the solutions are precisely the set $\{ 0, e^{2\pi m i/n} \;\; \text{with} \;\; 0 \le m \le n - 1 \}$.

Answer (score 1):

You let $z=re^{i\theta}$ where $r>0$ and $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$. $\overline{z} = z^{n-1}$, so $r e^{-i\theta}=r^{n-1} e^{i(n-1)\theta}$, hence $r^{n-2}e^{in\theta}=1$ hence $r^{n-2}=1$ and $ n \theta \equiv 0$ mod $2\pi$.  r=1, and $\theta =\frac{k2\pi}{n}$ where k is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not; for example, if $$z := e^{2 \pi i / 3} = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i,$$ then
$$\bar{z} = z^2 = z^{3 - 1},$$
and $3 > 2$.